# Gridview Not load when dropdownlist event fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

here is my ddl select index change event and inside i call LoadData() function.

**My Problem** is whenever i select new value in  dropdownlist my gridview can't bind according to that value.
FYI:

1. I give autopostback true to ddl.
2. Below total weekhours is pass parameter to store procedure and return correctly but i can't bind.

```
protected void ddlWeek_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
{ 
    LoadData(); 
}

private void LoadData()
{
    var res = obj.TotalWeekHours(iSsn, strddlWeek);
    Grid2.DataSource = res;
    Grid2.DataBind();
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Where do u set values of `iSsn` and `strddlWeek`? Also what type does `obj.TotalWeekHours` return - DataTable?

Comment: sorry i not mentioned.i pass iSsn and strddlweek inside the LoadData() Function.TotalWeekHours is a function in .dbml file.

Comment: Do you get an error message of some kind or does the data just not show up in the gridView?

Comment: i hard code iSsn and i get date from my ddl i store in  strddlWeek.

Comment: no error message.but in gridview bind take place when i click the button save method...in btn_save method i call same loaddata() function.but i want to bind when i select ddl.

Comment: Try the SelectedValueChanged event instead of the SelectedIndexChanged, just cut and paste your code into the new method.

Comment: No selectedvalueChanged event in my ddl.where to get it..FYI: i use radddl

Comment: Is Postback happens on SelectedIndexChanged? Can u put a breakpoint there and see that Res gets correct data?

Comment: @Yuriy i check the postback event it get correct data but my gridview can't reflect

Answer (score 0):

Put a break-point in that event handler and check the SelectedValue - I think you will see that it IS NOT updated to the value the user selected. This is a problem of the way the event handlers fire. The only solution I've found is to do my databinding based on the new value in PreRender. So, I think what's happening right now is: event handler fires and databinding occurs against the old selected value - making it look like nothing happened... but if you fire the event again (select a new value) you should see it update to the previously selected value. Like, it will be "behind" by one selection. Binding your data in PreRender is the only way I've found to consistently fix that.

Try it and let me know if you're getting "behind" by one selection if you do it over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for rply first..ya i put break point it select the correct ddl value and but can't bind to my gridview

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you grab the selected value and use it for anything? Maybe we need to see some more code?